# Git file deleted in working with no commit

Tags: git

On our project I have a file "KhachHangDonVi.cshtml" with last commmit for editing at 20210611, and today that file was deleted in my repository.

I checked all commit on the parent folder "View/DanhMuc" from 20210611 upto today and no change on that file was made (as image, tick all "show remote branchs, show local branch, view full history...")

How could that be possible?

And I saw one last commit on file "KhachHangDonVi.cshtml" is at 20210615 by user quanbm, but he did nothing to that file or the parent folder "DanhMuc". Why Git list his commit in here???

[image]

[image]

[image]

After readding file to repository, I found a git command to check history of deleted file, but now it seems can only view history of newly added file or somewhat (no history before re-adding file), and I couldn't read that with too much duplicated text...

FYI, translate comment "Day lai file KhachHangDonVi.cshtml bi mat tu lan commit cuoi 20210611"  to english: "Readd file KhachHangDonVi.cshtml that was lost from last commit in 20210611"

```
>git log --all --full-history --graph --name-status -- "**/KhachHangDonVi.cshtml"
*   commit 217c3b5348e19753f5fd2f308d9bce3280407c3a (origin/Working)
|\  Merge: d6d8e24d 32968a5f
| | Author: chinhpd <chinhpd@vnpt.vn>
| | Date:   Tue Jun 22 10:36:02 2021 +0000
| |
| |     Merge branch 'quanbm' into 'Working'
| |
| |     quanbm
| |
| |     See merge request scm.erp.it/PTPM2_KTTKV!292
| |
* |   commit d6d8e24def3135079ccd13c8cd8d9ec82efbd3ef
|\ \  Merge: 677ae21f 2197adfe
| | | Author: chinhpd <chinhpd@vnpt.vn>
| | | Date:   Tue Jun 22 08:53:03 2021 +0000
| | |
| | |     Merge branch 'feat/ht/KTTKV-35_them_makhachhang' into 'Working'
| | |
| | |     Day lai file KhachHangDonVi.cshtml bi mat tu lan commit cuoi 20210611 Commit ac7ee02f
| | |
| | |     See merge request scm.erp.it/PTPM2_KTTKV!293
| | |
| * | commit 2197adfe422664ad7714e8c3eb0b31694dc90662 (origin/feat/ht/KTTKV-35_them_makhachhang, feat/ht/KTTKV-35_them_makhachhang)
| | | Author: Pham X. Bach <pxbach@vnpt.vn>
| | | Date:   Tue Jun 22 15:52:21 2021 +0700
| | |
| | |     fix loi grid
| | |
| | | M TKV_New/TKV.Web/Views/DanhMuc/KhachHangDonVi.cshtml
| | |
| * | commit 17ecb5d7866462a06b050bcbb5b47a3c176ff13f
|/ /  Author: Pham X. Bach <pxbach@vnpt.vn>
| |   Date:   Tue Jun 22 15:45:00 2021 +0700
| |
| |       Day lai file KhachHangDonVi.cshtml bi mat tu lan commit cuoi 20210611 Commit ac7ee02f
| |
| |   A TKV_New/TKV.Web/Views/DanhMuc/KhachHangDonVi.cshtml
| |
| | * commit 26b59b5c4380033ea699d6e53d47e4da8e617057 (refs/stash)
| |/  Author: Pham X. Bach <pxbach@vnpt.vn>
|/|   Date:   Tue Jun 22 15:18:12 2021 +0700
| |
| |       On KTTKV-25_bo_ma_chi_tieu: stashTkv
| |
* |   commit 677ae21f9be91da3d1f463331a60cbf6092980be (HEAD -> Working)
|\ \  Merge: a7f6888b b0609d7e
| | | Author: chinhpd <chinhpd@vnpt.vn>
| | | Date:   Mon Jun 21 13:51:01 2021 +0000
| | |
| | |     Merge branch 'Working_tmp' into 'Working'
| | |
| | |     Bổ xung lấy năm BC
| | |
| | |     See merge request scm.erp.it/PTPM2_KTTKV!291
| | |
* | | commit a7f6888b627cc2d7bf7e0d93da9f1c1f12ed74b9
| | | Author: chinhpd <chinhpd@vnpt.vn>
| | | Date:   Mon Jun 21 13:20:50 2021 +0000
| | |
| | |     Merge branch 'feat/kt/KTTKV-25_bo_ma_chi_tieu' into 'Working'
| | |
| | |     Rollback lại commit Commit 08a33508 bị đẩy đè overwrite
| | |
| | |     See merge request scm.erp.it/PTPM2_KTTKV!290
| | |
* | |   commit 4289c293f3f344792f2e0023bb20eefd388254d1
|\ \ \  Merge: c8ba37d9 32968a5f
| | |/  Author: chinhpd <chinhpd@vnpt.vn>
| |/|   Date:   Mon Jun 21 12:21:36 2021 +0000
| | |
| | |       Merge branch 'quanbm' into 'Working'
| | |
| | |       Quanbm
| | |
| | |       See merge request scm.erp.it/PTPM2_KTTKV!289
| | |
| * |   commit 32968a5f5470c65d02c7dac443b1a4bc5128adcd
| |\ \  Merge: 5077a92d 37ef1cd6
| | | | Author: quanbm <minhquan10101991@gmail.com>
| | | | Date:   Mon Jun 21 19:20:14 2021 +0700
| | | |
_KTTKV into quanbm
| | | |
* | | |   commit c8ba37d9ba9ffedf37884b89cd0a2f6450842644
|\ \ \ \  Merge: c3de806b 3004d004
| | | | | Author: chinhpd <chinhpd@vnpt.vn>
| | | | | Date:   Mon Jun 21 12:20:25 2021 +0000
| | | | |
| | | | |     Merge branch 'feat/kt/KTTKV-25_bo_ma_chi_tieu' into 'Working'
| | | | |
 BA
| | | | |
| | | | |     See merge request scm.erp.it/PTPM2_KTTKV!288
| | | | |
* | | | |   commit c3de806b2657e10dc6eb8f3fafc7b0d0e2b7798e
|\ \ \ \ \  Merge: 28668ccf b0609d7e
| | |_|_|/  Author: chinhpd <chinhpd@vnpt.vn>
| |/| | |   Date:   Mon Jun 21 10:17:01 2021 +0000
| | | | |
| | | | |       Merge branch 'Working_tmp' into 'Working'
| | | | |
| | | | |       Update BCTK
| | | | |
| | | | |       See merge request scm.erp.it/PTPM2_KTTKV!287
| | | | |
| * | | |   commit b0609d7edce7c4862a8417984179bb2f7ecfaa9d
| |\ \ \ \  Merge: 64e106cf 68c511a6
| | | | | | Author: tieudoan208 <tieudoan208@hotmail.com>
| | | | | | Date:   Mon Jun 21 10:34:23 2021 +0700
| | | | | |
/scm.erp.it/PTPM2_KTTKV into Working_tmp
| | | | | |
| | * | | |   commit 68c511a60eac441a9cfae7f3678869458d2fd6e1
| | |\ \ \ \  Merge: db96887f 818e57d4
| | | | | | | Author: quydohut08 <ducchinh.hut@gmail.com>
| | | | | | | Date:   Fri Jun 18 14:45:20 2021 +0700
| | | | | | |
| | | | | | |     Merge branch 'Working' into ChinhPD/NhapChiTieu
| | | | | | |
| | * | | | |   commit db96887f27f86ec3727997c228083b85b42b3ff8
| | |\ \ \ \ \  Merge: d7d11064 37ef1cd6
| | | | |_|_|/  Author: chinhpd <chinhpd@vnpt.vn>
| | | |/| | |   Date:   Thu Jun 17 16:16:23 2021 +0700
| | | | | | |
| | | | | | |       Merge branch 'Working' into ChinhPD/NhapChiTieu
| | | | | | |
| | * | | | |   commit d7d110640d107a282fa2f011bd1addd255d89f1c
| | |\ \ \ \ \  Merge: f13ff43c 24da517f
| | | | | | | | Author: chinhpd <chinhpd@vnpt.vn>
| | | | | | | | Date:   Tue Jun 15 09:46:15 2021 +0700
| | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | |     Merge branch 'Working' into ChinhPD/NhapChiTieu
| | | | | | | |
| * | | | | | |   commit 64e106cf6dc5a1a9f4f34c450366e87eb65a46e2
| |\ \ \ \ \ \ \  Merge: bf0ce46c 28668ccf
| |/ / / / / / /  Author: tieudoan208 <tieudoan208@hotmail.com>
|/| | | | | | |   Date:   Sat Jun 19 10:39:24 2021 +0700
| | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | |        COMMIT
| | | | | | | |
* | | | | | | |   commit 28668ccf589e0e3bb9bdaf8dc701d94588d69e2e
|\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  Merge: 818e57d4 3004d004
| |_|_|_|_|/ / /  Author: pxbach <pxbach@vnpt.vn>
|/| | | | | / /   Date:   Fri Jun 18 08:01:33 2021 +0000
| | |_|_|_|/ /
ng'
| | | | | | |
| | | | | | |         Sua giao dien theo yeu cau BA
| | | | | | |
| | | | | | |         See merge request scm.erp.it/PTPM2_KTTKV!286
| | | | | | |
* | | | | | | commit 818e57d4c9bbc21bf85bc566a7da9de16850537f
|\| | | | | | Merge: c2207efc 3004d004
| | | | | | | Author: chinhpd <chinhpd@vnpt.vn>
| | | | | | | Date:   Fri Jun 18 07:33:56 2021 +0000
| | | | | | |
| | | | | | |     Merge branch 'feat/kt/KTTKV-25_bo_ma_chi_tieu' into 'Working'
| | | | | | |
| | | | | | |     Them bo ma chi tieu
| | | | | | |
| | | | | | |     See merge request scm.erp.it/PTPM2_KTTKV!285
| | | | | | |
| * | | | | |   commit 3004d0044de2328330d591539a2eea48ef371270
| |\ \ \ \ \ \  Merge: 24da517f c2207efc
| |/ / / / / /  Author: Pham X. Bach <pxbach@vnpt.vn>
|/| | | / / /   Date:   Fri Jun 18 10:12:46 2021 +0700
| | |_|/ / /
.it/pm6_kttkv into feat/kt/KTTKV-25_bo_ma_chi_tieu
| | | | | |
| | | | | |         # Conflicts:
| | | | | |         #       TKV_New/TKV.Web/wwwroot/js/site.Staging.js
| | | | | |
* | | | | |   commit c2207efce69ed217a54b54d9f697833a54bc710e
|\ \ \ \ \ \  Merge: 37ef1cd6 5077a92d
| |_|_|_|/ /  Author: quydohut08 <ducchinh.hut@gmail.com>
|/| | | | /   Date:   Fri Jun 18 08:49:11 2021 +0700
| | |_|_|/
| |/| | |         Merge branch 'ChinhPD/ChiTieuDonVi' into Working
| | | | |
* | | | | commit 37ef1cd6a00a6953184fcd0e432c482e4f4bbbde
|/ / / /  Author: chinhpd <chinhpd@vnpt.vn>
| | | |   Date:   Thu Jun 17 16:12:36 2021 +0700
| | | |
| | | |       Merge branch 'ChinhPD/ChiTieuDonVi' into quanbm
| | | |
* | | | commit 5077a92d902264fec5a928b8a92203f4d44f7929
|\| | | Merge: 157905f7 24da517f
| | | | Author: quanbm <minhquan10101991@gmail.com>
| | | | Date:   Tue Jun 15 08:46:42 2021 +0700
| | | |
| | | |     quanbm
| | | |
| | * |   commit bf0ce46ca8b4dedc3deb92cefc5db93dde056778
| | |\ \  Merge: 7854e633 24da517f
| | |/ /  Author: tieudoan208 <tieudoan208@hotmail.com>
| |/| |   Date:   Sat Jun 19 10:30:09 2021 +0700
| | | |
| | | |       BCTK
| | | |
| * | | commit 24da517fbe0dcdcc29be9d13e002629468ba4f2b
| | |/  Author: Pham X. Bach <pxbach@vnpt.vn>
| |/|   Date:   Tue Jun 15 08:32:19 2021 +0700
| | |
kttkv into Working
| | |
| | |       # Conflicts:
| | |       #       TKV_New/TKV.Web/Views/DanhMuc/BaoCaoTuKhai.cshtml
| | |
| | * commit 7854e6331c0341a840f222f656d69e8e58625071
| |/| Merge: 157905f7 f13ff43c
|/|/  Author: tieudoan208 <tieudoan208@hotmail.com>
| |   Date:   Tue Jun 15 09:17:29 2021 +0700
| |
KTTKV into Working_tmp
| |
| * commit f13ff43cf047fb3088dab2319adce9bdcd15cfcf
| | Author: quydohut08 <ducchinh.hut@gmail.com>
| | Date:   Fri Jun 11 17:40:55 2021 +0700
| |
| |     Fix warning
| |
| | M   TKV_New/TKV.Web/Views/DanhMuc/KhachHangDonVi.cshtml
| |
| *   commit aa83661713163a6b0a6d82c37bfb79ad6429825c
| |\  Merge: 464d53c1 157905f7
| |/  Author: quydohut08 <ducchinh.hut@gmail.com>
|/|   Date:   Fri Jun 11 17:34:14 2021 +0700
| |
| |       Merge branch 'ChinhPD/QuanLyNguoiDung' into Working
| |
| *   commit 464d53c13b4c6412f255a0967868f2fde72b7732
| |\  Merge: 116a264f ac7ee02f
| | | Author: pxbach <pxbach@vnpt.vn>
| | | Date:   Fri Jun 11 09:37:45 2021 +0000
| | |
| | |     Merge branch 'feat/ht/KTTKV-35_them_makhachhang' into 'Working'
| | |
| | |     Them form ma khach hang don vi
| | |
| | |     See merge request scm.erp.it/PTPM2_KTTKV!282
| | |
| | * commit ac7ee02f1dc530fbf588d314a6edcb8250b74c67
| | | Author: Pham X. Bach <pxbach@vnpt.vn>
| | | Date:   Fri Jun 11 16:36:13 2021 +0700
| | |
| | |     Them form ma khach hang don vi
| | |
| | | M TKV_New/TKV.Web/Views/DanhMuc/KhachHangDonVi.cshtml
| | |
```

**Edited 20210623:** As our company has a scm page, today I checked for all merge request (MR) from my last MR that make edit to that file, and found the MR that delete that file. But weird that I check all 18 commits on that MR and no commit do delete it?

I even tried going further by using GUI popup in scm but no luck finding what happen...

[image]

................................................................................................................................

[image]

................................................................................................................................

[image]

................................................................................................................................

[image]

Comment: It doesn't say it was deleted, only modified.

Comment: @evolutionxbox the problem is that we lost that file in the lastest version of repository. And now I must re-add that file and make a new merge request to get it back to our repository, after hours cannot find the reason or any commit that delete it :(

Comment: If the file is gone, there must be a commit that deleted it. If you can't figure out which commit, it might be a merge commit. Merge commits are not shown as clearly in the history because of the two-parent business, it's not a straightforward diff to show. You mention commit "20210615 by user quanbm" and wonder why it's listed. That's the one I would suspect. When you checkout that commit, is the file still there?

Comment: @PhamX.Bach : try adding `--graph --name-status` to your `git log` command. `--graph` will give you a clearer view of what commit is the parent of what commit, `--name-status` will show you what files are tracked and what happened to them (creation/modification/deletion)